# Скрыть все организации на картах кроме своей

Tags: yandex-maps-api, google-maps-api

Можно ли на картах яндекс или гугл скрыть все иконки организаций (чтобы не отвлекали) поблизости, кроме той которая необходима?

Comment: Рекомендую уточнить среду, где будет карта. На сайте? В Android приложении? В зависимости от этого так же установите соответствующие теги

Comment: Использоваться на сайте.

Answer (score 1):

В JS API Яндекс.Карт используется тайловая графика - вся карта отдаётся пользователям уже в отрисованном растровом виде и сразу вместе с POI организаций.

Поэтому возможности получить через API Яндекс карту без POI нет.

Для привлечения внимания именно к своей организации лучше как-то выделить на карте её саму. Например кастомизированной крупной меткой или открытым балуном с выделяющимся оформлением.